# propfind android

Tags: android, httpclient, webdav

I am trying to use propfind in android.I am new to webdav. I have added the Jackrabbit jar to my project. I have no clue as to how to use the PROPFIND please suggest me any sites or any code that can get the list of files.

I am using the code but I am getting an exception:

```
HostConfiguration config=new HostConfiguration();
config.setHost("");
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager manager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
params.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(config, 5);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(manager);
client.setHostConfiguration(config);

try {
  PropFindMethod propfind=new PropFindMethod("https://",PropFindMethod.PROPFIND_ALL_PROP,1);
  Credentials creds=new UsernamePasswordCredentials("XXXX", "XXXXX");
  client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

  int Status=client.executeMethod(propfind);
  Log.d("Status",Status+"");
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ERROR:

```
05-31 18:08:49.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29145): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Please help.  Thankyou in advance

Comment: are you sure you're android projet has the right to exploit everything you want in your manifest ? and is your Activity declare in your manifest ?